# Java - Cannot resolve symbol of in LocalDate.of

Tags: java, date, intellij-idea, symbols

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate ld = new LocalDate.of(2000,10,20);
    }
}
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3. When I try to use LocalDate.of it shows "Cannot resolve symbol 'of'". I tried typing "o" and then enter but it still doesn't work. When trying to compile and run it says:

```
"Error:(14, 37) java: cannot find symbol 
symbol:   class of
location: class java.time.LocalDate"
```

Comment: `LocalDate` is new with Java 8, so you are probably using an older JDK?

Comment: How can this `new LocalDate.of` make sense? You're calling `new` _and_ a static factory method? Both at the same time?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because of your `new` operator, you are attempting to instantiate a nested class called `of` within `LocalDate`, which does not exist.

Remove `new` so it can parse as the `static` method `of` within `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld =  LocalDate.of(2000,10,20);
```